# Gmail Filters Limit

Tags: gmail-api

I have read through online sources and it is described that there is no limit to the number of filters that don't forward to other email addresses. However, I receive a HttpError 400 "Too many filters" when creating additional filters with a mailbox that has ~1088 filters. Most all of these will add/remove labels based on query criteria.

What is the true limit to the number of filters that a mailbox can have?

Comment: Did you find any answer to this? What is the limit?

Answer (score 1):

According to the API documentation, the limit is 1,000 filters (for filters that don't forward to other email addresses).

> Note: you can only create a maximum of 1,000 filters.

Source: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters/create

Answer (score 0):

There's no certain limit when creating filters in Gmail, therefore you can create an unlimited number of filters. You are only allowed to create 20 individual filters that forward to different addresses. You can edit existing filters whenever you need to forward to different email addresses. The only way to bypass this limit is by combining filters if multiple filters apply to the same email address. Check this [blogpost](https://itstillworks.com/maximum-amount-filters-email-addresses-gmail-4187.html) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found this blogpost to not be true as I receive a HttpError "Too many filters" now on filter creation.

Comment: If that's the case, you can try to log an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com) here.